# Manually adding test case in test lab without test plan in HP ALM

Tags: alm

Is it possible to manually typing test case in test lab without moving from test plan in HP ALM?

Comment: Simple answer - NO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Test Plan is the collection of tests existing in project. So you require to add it to Test Plan first. And than create test set that could have a test from Test Plan.